# Como remover arquivo incluindo com include de acordo com condições

Tags: php

Dei uma pesquisada básica e não encontrei nada. Imagino que deva ser algo simples, e que eu possa estar "procurando errado"...

Então por exemplo:

```
<?php
    if ($var1 != "qualquercoisa") {
        include "arquivo1.php";
    }
    elseif ($var2 == "outracoisa") {
        include "arquivo2.php";
        **remove** "arquivo1.php";
    }
?>
```

Existe um comando que faça isso, ou tenho que fazer de outro jeito, tipo com `switch`?

Comment: Oi Gustavo, eu respondi, mas gostaria de saber o objetivo disto, por que assim posso talvez lhe sugerir uma alternativa para fazer algo semelhante :)

Comment: Não seria melhor criar uma função que retorna um array com todos includes e depois apenas invocar eles?

Comment: @rray Ótima estratégia +1 vale uma resposta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento as variáveis recebem as informações de um formulário, e dependendo da escolha de um select por exemplo, eu incluo um arquivo com um bloco de texto (vai formar um texto completo juntando estes blocos)... Deu pra entender? Então às vezes eu tenho que trocar estes blocos, porque uma escolha posterior (num select em outra página) inclui outro arquivo ao invés daquele que seria incluido se a escolha anterior não afetasse a posterior...

Comment: @rray e como eu faria isso? Pode dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O processo do PHP não é algo "assincrono", o arquivo incluído é executado como se *fosse parte* do arquivo que o está incluindo.

Supondo que você tem `a.php`:

```
<?php
echo 1;
```

E `b.php`:

```
<?php
include 'a.php';
echo 2;
```

Para o interpretador do PHP, vai ser o "mesmo" que:

```
<?php
echo 1;
echo 2;
```

Isto é semelhante ao C/C++ aonde o arquivo incluído é compilado "junto" com o arquivo que inclui.

**Não** tem como "remover" o arquivo incluído, note também que `include` e `require` não são funções.

Outra coisa (não estou certo disto), softwares *opcache* para PHP geram versões já processadas do PHP, neste caso o arquivo incluído é processado junto do que inclui, como se fosse apenas um arquivo (eu acho).

### Altenativa

Conforme o @rray sugeriu, você pode chamar os includes após as ifs, utilizando uma array por exemplo, seria algo como:

```
<?php
$includes = array();

if (condicao1) {
   $includes[] = 'file1.php';

   if (condicao2) {//condição dois
       $includes[] = 'file2.php';
   } else {
       $includes[] = 'file3.php';
   }
} else {
   $includes[] = 'file4.php';

   if (condicao2) {//Aqui repete a condição dois
       $includes[] = 'file2.php';
   }
}

foreach($key as $includes) {
   include $key;
}
```

- Se `condicao1` e `condicao2` forem `true` ele vai incluir os arquivos `file1.php` e `file2.php`
- Se `condicao1` for `true` e `condicao2` for `false` ele vai incluir os arquivos `file1.php` e `file3.php`
- Se `condicao1` for `false` e `condicao2` for `true` ele vai incluir os arquivos `file4.php` e `file2.php`
- Se `condicao1` for `false` e `condicao2` for `false` ele vai incluir apenas o arquivo `file4.php`

Comment: Legal! Tudo ficou mais claro! :-) Valeu! +1

Answer (score 3):

**Não existe forma de remover um ficheiro já incluído.**

---

> O código é interpretado no lado do servidor pelo módulo PHP, que também gera a página web a ser visualizada no lado do cliente.

Isto quer dizer que a cada vez que o utilizador dá um refresh na página ou abre a página esta envia um requisito ao servidor e o servidor interpreta o código no lado do servidor (*server-side*).

O que eu quero dizer com isto é que não existiria necessidade de remover a include visto que quando é feito um novo requisito é feito tudo do inicio, logo, se tivermos uma condição:

```
if($var == true)
{
    include "file1.php";
} else {
    include "file2.php";
}
```

No primeiro pedido se a variável `$var` for igual a `true` o ficheiro `file1.php` será incluído, mas se for feito outro pedido e a variável `$var` for `falsa` o ficheiro `file2.php` será incluido e o ficheiro `file1.php` não existira, isto porque, como eu disse, quando é feito um requisito ele começa de novo.

---

Fiz um pequeno código para exemplificar isso, testa por ti mesmo.

**TestB.php**

```
<?php
echo "Hello from A";
```

**TestA.php**

```
<?php
echo "Hello from A";
```

**Test.php**

```
<?php

$var = $_GET['n'];

switch($var)
{
    case 1:
    {
        include "testA.php";
        break;
    }
    case 2: 
    {
        include "testB.php";
        break;
    }
}
```

Verificarás que ao mudar o valor de **n** no link (test.php?**n=1** ou test.php?**n=2**) o ficheiro anterior existente não estará incluído.

Comment: Boa resposta, valeu! Gostei da ideia com o switch. Vou estudar melhor aqui as opções que surgiram. +1

Answer (score 2):

Como dito nas outras respostas não é possível remover um arquivo já incluido.
Sugiro algo flexivel como dada uma entrada uma função ela retornará um (gabarito) array com todos arquivos que devem ser incluidos, após isso é feito um foreach.

```
function gabarito($entradas){
   $arquivos = array('config.php', 'segurancao.php');

   if($entrada['perfil'] == 'admin'){
      $arquivos[] = 'perfil/admin.php';
   }elseif($entrada['perfil'] == 'anon'){
     $arquivos[] = '/perfil.anon.php';
     unset($arquivos[0]); //remove as configurações do usuario como temas
   }

   return $arquivos;
}


$arquivos = gabarito($entradas);
foreach($arquivos as $item){
   include $item;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_included_files());
```

Pode ver os arquivos incluidos com a função [get_included_files()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php), também pode ser interessante definir uma constante com o prefixo de algumas pastas.

Comment: Então, eu ainda não estou usando sessões, mas gostei da solução com foreach... a ideia da outra resposta com switch também parece boa... vou estudar aqui melhor, acho que terei que rever a lógica que estava pensando (só com `ifs`). Valeu pela resposta, acho que em breve (quando implantar o controle de usuários) será ainda mais útil que agora! +1

Comment: Dependendo da complexidade vc pode criar configurações/perfils e gravar/recuperar do banco de dados e tratar com a sessão. Exemplo perfil 1, carrega o `config` e o `admin`, perfil 2 carrega, `somente_leitura` e `interface_basica`. @gustavox

Comment: Legal, é bem isso mesmo que vou ter que fazer em breve. Por enquanto estou usando apenas em localhost, desenvolvendo ainda, mas em breve terei que me aprofundar em sessões, já até arrumei uns livros, porque sei que esta parte será um dos maiores (banco de dados, sessões etc) desafios do meu projeto... valeu mesmo!

Comment: +1 pela ótima ideia (rray é o estrategista dos códigos o/ )